# Struggling with this PDA construction

Tags: pushdown-automaton

[image]

In human language: list of words (constructed from ‘a’s and ‘b’s ) separated by ‘c’s and exists at least one word in some index i that has more letters ‘a’ in it then word in index i+2

Comment: So i am asking for help to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

A sample NPDA:

Push all a's of  some w(i) into the stack, throw away(skip) w(i+1)'s letters, match w(i+2) a's with what is in the stack. If some a's remained in the stack, go to the final state.